# cordova-plugin-sketch losing quality on multiple edits

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, android-bitmap

I'm utilizing the `cordova-plugin-sketch` plugin and I'm having an issue on Android where the quality of the image is degrading upon each render/save. One of the maintainers has been nice enough to provide a few links to help resolve the issue but I've so far been unsuccessful. I'm fairly new to Android development which is part of the problem.

Plugin:
https://github.com/blinkmobile/cordova-plugin-sketch

Issue:
https://github.com/blinkmobile/cordova-plugin-sketch/issues/3

I've tried setting different options for `inDensity` and `inTargetDensity` on `BitmapFactory.Options` on but haven't found any settings that improve the quality. Also, I imagine the effectiveness of these settings would change based on the device being used.

File being edited: `TouchDrawActivity.java`

What I've tried changing:

```
mBitmap = createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, mTdView.mCanvas.getWidth(),
            mTdView.mCanvas.getHeight(),ScalingLogic.FIT);
//mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mTdView.mCanvas.getWidth(),mTdView.mCanvas.getHeight(),false);
```

is now using this code:

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, ScalingLogic scalingLogic)
{
    Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(), dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}

public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, ScalingLogic scalingLogic)
{
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP)
    {
        final float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect)
        {
            final int srcRectWidth = (int) (srcHeight * dstAspect);
            final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
            return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            final int srcRectHeight = (int) (srcWidth / dstAspect);
            final int scrRectTop = (int) (srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
            return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
    }
}

public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, ScalingLogic scalingLogic)
{
    if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT)
    {
        final float srcAspect = (float) srcWidth / (float) srcHeight;
        final float dstAspect = (float) dstWidth / (float) dstHeight;

        if (srcAspect > dstAspect)
        {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int) (dstWidth / srcAspect));
        }
        else
        {
            return new Rect(0, 0, (int) (dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the image degradation seems to be nearly if not identical.

Comment: I've seen this issue too and it looks like the plugin creates a new version of the image every time you open, edit, and then re-save the image. This new version is a compressed version of the previous compressed version and so you loose more and more each save. Unfortunately I don't know away around it. If you don't care about previous edits, maybe its possible have two versions of the photo saved. One being the original and then each new edit is a copy from the original or and not the previous copy. Also, maybe see if you can use a lossless format like a png.